# [Nodejs - Crypto][JSencrypt] rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error

Tags: node.js, encryption, rsa, node-crypto, jsencrypt

I'm using [NodeJS Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) module for encrypting and decrypting with RSA in backend and [JSencrypt](https://github.com/travist/jsencrypt) for frontend RSA

But issue is my backend throws this error whenever I encrypt in frontend using publickey (PS: I'm using this in NuxtJS so using import function.)

```js
const { JSEncrypt } = await import('jsencrypt')
const rsa = new JSEncrypt({ default_key_size: 1024 })
rsa.setPublicKey(store.state.publicKey)
const xKey = rsa.encrypt(store.state.ticket)
```

and then whenever I try to decode using this piece of code in my backend it throws this

```
Error: error:04099079:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_OAEP_mgf1:oaep decoding error
```

Here is my backend code for RSA decoding using privateKey

```js
const privateKey = fs.readFileSync('RSA_private.key', { encoding: 'utf8' })

exports.RSAdecrypt = async (data) => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data, "base64")
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt(privateKey, buffer)
    return decrypted.toString('utf8')
}
```

Comment: trying asymmetric encryption ? pkcs padding issue maybe.

Comment: @HarshManvar how do i set custom padding? please guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. I saw on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953732/node-js-correct-way-to-make-rsa-encrypt) that `JSencrypt` uses `pkcs1` padding by default. so I have changed my decryptor with `pkcs1` Bydefault node crypto uses `pkcs1_oaep` by default.

here is code for decryptor.

```js
exports.RSAdecrypt = async (data) => {
    const buffer = Buffer.from(data, "base64")
    const decrypted = crypto.privateDecrypt({ key: privateKey, padding: crypto.constants.RSA_PKCS1_PADDING }, buffer)
    return decrypted.toString('utf8')
}
```

Comment: I'm using [crypto-browserify](https://github.com/crypto-browserify/crypto-browserify) to encrypt on the frontend. When I decrypt on the backend I get 
```error:0407109F:rsa routines:RSA_padding_check_PKCS1_type_2:pkcs decoding error```
It seems like neither `pkcs1` nor `pkcs1_oaep` padding works for `crypto-browserify`. Do you have any suggestions for what to try next?

Answer (score 4):

If people are still having errors, because I got a different error when I did the same thing as the answer here, you might want to pass the crypto constant no padding like this:

```js
crypto.privateDecrypt(
      {
        key: this.privateKey,
        passphrase: '<passPhrase>',
        padding: crypto.constants.RSA_NO_PADDING, // <-- You might want to try this
      }, 
      Buffer.from(encryptedText, 'base64')).toString('utf8');
```